# scanf a string and printf it in C

Tags: c, string, printf, scanf

What I can do to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void lee(char s[]);
void escribe(char s[]);

int main()
{
    char str[20];
    char ch;

    printf("1 escribe\n2 lee\n");
    ch=getchar();
    switch(ch) {
        case '1': 
            printf("you are in escribe (write)\n");
            lee(str);
            break;
        case '2': 
            printf("you are in lee (read)\n");
            escribe(str);            
            break;
        default: puts("Error");
    }


    return 0;
}

void lee(char s[]){
    printf("write your sentense\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
}

void escribe(char s[]){
    printf("Entered string is %s \n", s);
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work". What happens? What should happen?

Comment: when I go to lee, i can't write

Comment: Don't add all sorts of panic "help me plzzzzz" text to your question. Instead, stop, take a deep breath, and explain what the problem is in more detail.

Comment: First I recommend you to clean up your code. Your printf says one thing and the methods called are in wrong places. Include clean description what you want result you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying this is good code, but I "think" this is kind of what you are trying to do.
Maybe it will give you an idea so you can fix your code the way you want it.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void lee(char s[]);
    void escribe(char s[]);

    int main()
    {
        char str[20] = {0};
        char ch = '\0';


        while(1)
        {
            printf("\n1 escribe:\n2 lee:\n");
            ch = getchar();
            fseek(stdin, 0, 0);

            switch(ch) {
                case '1' :
                    printf("\nYou are in escribe (write)\n\n");
                    lee(str);
                    break;

                case '2' :
                    printf("\nYou are in lee (read)\n\n");
                    escribe(str);
                    break;

                default: puts("Error");
                    exit(1);
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }

void lee(char s[]){
    printf("Write your sentence: \n");
    scanf("%19[^\n]", s);
    fseek(stdin, 0,0);
    printf("\n");
}

void escribe(char s[]){
    printf("The entered string is: %s ", s);
    printf("\n");
}
```